# How to save array in RAM and make a search for an entry

Tags: php

I'm trying to generate a number and save it in an array in RAM and then search for a match.

This is what my code should do:

-Generate a number

-Save it in a variable (array)

-Open a txt file and find a match from that array against the list of numbers in list.txt

-if found save it to Bingo.txt

```
<?php

function Fun()
{

    $list = fopen("list.txt", "r");
    $result = "BINGOOOOOO.txt";
    //$command = "generatenumber.exe";
    //$generatednumber = shell_exec($command);
    $generatednumber = "1";

    $matches = array();

    if ($list) {
        while ($getLine = fgets($list)) {
            $getLine = rtrim($getLine); // remove newline
            $source = $generatednumber;
            var_dump($source);
            if ($source) {
                while ($buffer = fgets($source)) {
                    $buffer = rtrim($buffer);
                    if (in_array($getLine, explode(' ', $buffer)))
                        $matches[] = $buffer;
                }
                unset($source);
            }
        }
    }
    //show results:
    print_r($matches);
    $SaveResult = file_put_contents($matches, $result);
}
```

The issue now is that with number 1, bingo.txt file not created.

Comment: You mean save it in RAM over the lifetime of the usual request/response loop? If yes, then you'd need some form of a memcache

Comment: Did you mean to call the function `Fun` from inside the function `Fun`?

Comment: ___The issue now is that bingo.txt file not created.___ Well I dont see anywhere where you open or write to the `BINGOOOOOO.txt` Are you expecting output by Magic?

Comment: I re-updated the code guys

Comment: You call `Fun($generatednumber);` with a parameter, but the function prototype `function Fun()` does not have a parameter

Comment: It might have been useful to see at least an example of the `list.txt` file as well

Comment: @Lars Stegelitz Yes, a loop will be used, isn't putting the generated number in a variable then unset it would do the job?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I removed that line because it's incorrect. also list.txt has only number "1"

Comment: `file_put_contents($matches, $result);` Param1 is supposed to be the filename and Param2 the data to write to the file.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Hmm so what should I replace that with?

Comment: Hit the PHP manual, there are a number of mistakes in the code that a simple check in the manual would probably fix and you woudl learn something on the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All sorts of issues in your code

- An `fgets()` loop inside and `fgets()` loop will loose rows from your input
- Move some of the code outside the loop, it sits better there
- Get the function to return the results to you reather than outputting things itself.

```
function Fun($generatednumber)
{

    $list = fopen("list.txt", "r");
    //$command = "generatenumber.exe";
    //$generatednumber = shell_exec($command);

    $matches = array();

    if ($list) {
        while ($getLine = fgets($list)) {
            $getLine = rtrim($getLine); // remove newline
            
            if (in_array($generatednumber, explode(' ', $getLine))) {
                $matches[] = $getLine;
            }
        }
    }
    return $matches;
}

$in = 1;
$matches = Fun($in);

$result = "BINGOOOOOO.txt";
$SaveResult = file_put_contents($result, $matches);
```

Comment: Thank you, which is fast in your opinion, generate a number and save it into a txt file then  search for a match or save it in memory and search from ram?

Comment: I would consider using the [SESSION](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)